# How to search for a string and highlight adjacent words?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large MS Word document. To find information at a later date, I created an index to identify important subjects. A drawback to using indexes in MS Word is that they only show the page number of the information they are referencing (not the indexed words or sentence). I would like to highlight the section of the page that relates to the index (to make it easier to locate).

When creating an index, MS Word adds the index entry e.g. {XE "*Index Phrase*"} after the word or phrase being indexed. This index entry is only visible if viewing the document with formatting marks turned on. I found the below code and tweaked it a little to find the index by searching for "^d" and change the font color.

For users who don't want to view the document with formatting marks on, I would like to highlight the word or ideally sentence adjacent to the index entry.

I tried adjusting the code with the `Moveleft` method.

```vb
Sub ChangeWordColors()
    Dim vWords As Variant
    Dim sWord As Variant

    vWords = Array("^d")

    For Each sWord In vWords
        
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
                
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = sWord
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
    Next sWord
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a for each to work your way through ActiveDocument.Fields.  Test if the field is  XE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Fld As Field, Rng As Range
For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
  If Fld.Type = wdFieldIndexEntry Then
    Set Rng = Fld.Code
    With Rng
      .Start = .Start - 1
      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
      .MoveStart Unit:=wdSentence, Count:=-1
      .Font.Color = wdColorRed
    End With
  End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Do note, though, that VBA has no idea what a grammatic sentence is.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed.  Thank you.